# Unexplained terminal behaviour with VS Codium

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, vscodium

I've recently swapped from VSCode to Codium and I'm having some real trouble setting up the terminal.  It has some really strange behaviour, almost like it's in a `chroot` or something.  For example;

```
# VSCodium Terminal
$ ls /usr/bin | wc -l
1055
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/sh
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
5.2.21(1)-release
```

```
# System terminal (gnome-terminal)
$ ls /usr/bin | wc -l
1904
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
5.1.16(1)-release
```

There are some commands missing from the Codium terminal that I've installed on my system, plus a different Python version and so on.  I've tried following multiple different answers on SO and other places, and now my Codium preferences look like;

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash",
    "terminal.explorerKind": "external",
    "terminal.external.linuxExec": "/bin/bash",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "bash": {
            "path": "bash",
            "icon": "terminal-bash",
            "args": ["-l"]
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": true,
    "terminal.integrated.enablePersistentSessions": false
}
```

I've also tried setting `terminal.external.linuxExec": "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal",` but that makes no difference.

I'm clearly missing *something*, but I don't even know what to call what's going on and so I can't do any effective searching.

When I open a Codium terminal I am certain that it's running my `.bashrc`, because it's complaining about an unknown command `bc` - which I have in my profile.  When I open a Gnome Terminal, `bc` is available and this I don't get any errors.  Also the custom `git` prompt and similar are present in the Codium terminal.

All I'm trying to achieve is for the Codium terminal to behave exactly like my system's normal terminal.  I'm using the latest PopOS (Ubuntu derivative), Codium 1.85.0 and Gnome Terminal 3.44.0.  Can anyone tell me what configuration I'm missing?

Comment: I have a similar issue with the VSCodium installation on my Linux Mint machine. I figured out that something fishy is going in with the `$PATH` variable, because it lacks many directories of my normal PATH, but has `/app/bin` thrice. So far I couldn't figure out how to fix this